# BFS algorithm in python for solving repeated node

Tags: python, algorithm, breadth-first-search

This is my code of BFS algorithm. I use it to solve the pecman problem and other test. But when i meet the problem of repeated node, it can't be solved. 
I think the outcome should be A-C-D-F-G. More over, I think the main problem is that I use dictionary as the method of storing the route. However, I don't know why the dictionary can't solve the repeated node problem.

BTW, I'm sure other parts have no problem.

```
def breadthFirstSearch(problem):
    """
    Search the shallowest nodes in the search tree first.
    """
    from util import Queue
    getpoint = Queue()
    currentpoint = problem.getStartState()
    getpoint.push(currentpoint)
    step = [ ]
    route = {currentpoint:step}
    checklist = []
    while getpoint.isEmpty()==False:
        currentpoint = getpoint.pop()
        if problem.isGoalState(currentpoint):
            print route[currentpoint]
            return route[currentpoint]
        else:
            if currentpoint not in checklist:
                checklist.append(currentpoint) 
                for x in problem.getSuccessors(currentpoint):
                    if x[0] not in checklist:
                        temp = route[currentpoint]
                        y = temp + [x[1]]
                        route[x[0]] = y
                        getpoint.push(x[0])
    util.raiseNotDefined()
```

[the outcome of the test in this picture, Please click it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYzl4.png)

Comment: You should post the output directly here, rather than an external link...

Comment: I'm sorry to do that. But it doesn't like code. So i don't find a way to attach it directly.

Comment: You've posted code above? Just indent it 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a `route` for the whole search, back tracking means you need to have a `route` per node pop'ed off the `Queue`, so push the `route` onto the Queue, e.g.:

```
getpoint.push((currentpoint, {currentpoint:step}))
...
while getpoint.isEmpty()==False:
    currentpoint, route = getpoint.pop()
    ...

            new_route = dict(route)  # New route
            new_route[x[0]] = y
            getpoint.push((x[0], new_route))
```

Note: you don't need the `else` clause as you `return` from the `if` clause.
Note: sometimes it is cleaner to `continue` on a loop than a large indented block
Note: a list of output nodes is sufficient without using a dictionary and much easier to manage
Note: `set()` is a much better data structure for `checklist`

Your updated code with some tidy up:

```
def breadthFirstSearch(problem):
    """
    Search the shallowest nodes in the search tree first.
    """
    from util import Queue
    getpoint = Queue()
    currentpoint = problem.getStartState()
    getpoint.push((currentpoint, []))
    checklist = set()
    while not getpoint.isEmpty():
        currentpoint, route = getpoint.pop()
        if problem.isGoalState(currentpoint):
            print route
            return route
        if currentpoint in checklist:
            continue
        checklist.add(currentpoint) 
        for nextpoint, action in problem.getSuccessors(currentpoint):
            getpoint.push((nextpoint, route+[action]))
    return None
```

Comment: I really appreciate the solution you wrote. I just use your solution to fix my code. Although it also has some mistakes, I try my best to understand your code and fix these mistakes. I think i could fix it tomorrow. I live in HongKong. Now it is 1:00 am.  So i should go to sleep because i have a class tomorrow morning. I'm really happy you could help me solve this problem. Thanks you.

Comment: Good, I don't have the data or the classes you reference to be able to test myself so hard for me to spot any mistakes but hopefully this gives you the general ideas to solve the problem yourself.